# Problems with VC++ directories macros after installation of Visual Studio 2107 community edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I've just installed the latest version of Visual Studio Community edition (15.7.9). I need only C++ currently. I failed to compile not only my previous projects, but the projects generated by this version of Visual Studio itself! All standard include files (,  and so on)  were not found.
After examination of the problem I discovered that inherited default values for include directories had wrong values.
For example current inherited values are:

> $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include

where as it should be:

> $(VCInstallDir)Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;
>
> $(VCInstallDir)Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include

Note that macros $(VC_IncludePath) and others had correct values.
I didn't meet this problem in previous versions of VS 2017 on my previous computers.

The question is: can I change such inherited default values since editing VC directories in every project is annoying (especially in generated ones!)

Comment: Surely "previous projects" is the cause.  Use View > Other Windows > Property Manager to see what project property sheets get used.

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot solve the problem as a whole but particular solution is to edit any project which I've created or opened the first time - just add the line $(VC_IncludePath) to Project settings-VC++ directories.
It's strange that I need to do do it by hand every time - may be beacause I've installed VS2017 from scratch on clean computer. Previously I hadn't such problems when upgraded from previous versions